# Btrfs "no space left" for any operation

Tags: btrfs

I've run out of space on my btrfs device and all the troubleshooting tips lead to the same error.  I am mounting with `sudo mount -o rw,skip_balance,nodatacow`.  I'm on kernel 6.1.13, and I do not have any subvolumes or snapshots.

`echo "" > largefile"` aborts the transaction:

```
[  438.953007] BTRFS: error (device sdf: state A) in __btrfs_update_delayed_inode:1060: errno=-28 No space left
[  438.953059] BTRFS info (device sdf: state EA): forced readonly
[  438.953064] BTRFS: error (device sdf: state EA) in __btrfs_run_delayed_items:1153: errno=-28 No space left
[  438.953100] BTRFS warning (device sdf: state EA): Skipping commit of aborted transaction.
[  438.953102] BTRFS: error (device sdf: state EA) in cleanup_transaction:1958: errno=-28 No space left
```

additional info there says `space_info METADATA has 4321902592 free, is full`

`btrfs balance start -v -dusage=0 /mnt` always says another balance is paused, or I can get the following error:

```
[ 1023.356909] BTRFS: error (device sdf: state A) in cleanup_transaction:1958: errno=-28 No space left
[ 1023.356969] BTRFS warning (device sdf: state EA): btrfs_uuid_scan_kthread failed -30
[ 1023.357006] BTRFS: error (device sdf: state EA) in reset_balance_state:3599: errno=-30 Readonly filesystem
```

The last tip I see is to add a new device.  I've tried with a loopback device and a real disk (`btrfs device add /dev/sdb /mnt`).  Both times I get:

```
[ 1393.030477] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): dumping space info:
[ 1393.030479] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): space_info DATA has 14588968960 free, is not full
[ 1393.030482] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): space_info total=11980400689152, used=11965811326976, pinned=0, reserved=0, may_use=0, readonly=393216 zone_unusable=0
[ 1393.030485] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): space_info METADATA has 4322557952 free, is not full
[ 1393.030487] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): space_info total=21944598528, used=17084776448, pinned=0, reserved=0, may_use=536870912, readonly=393216 zone_unusable=0
[ 1393.030490] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): space_info SYSTEM has 11780096 free, is not full
[ 1393.030492] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): space_info total=12582912, used=802816, pinned=0, reserved=0, may_use=0, readonly=0 zone_unusable=0
[ 1393.030495] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): global_block_rsv: size 536870912 reserved 536870912
[ 1393.030497] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): trans_block_rsv: size 0 reserved 0
[ 1393.030499] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): chunk_block_rsv: size 0 reserved 0
[ 1393.030500] BTRFS info (device sdf: state A): delayed_block_rsv: size 0 reserved 0
[ 1393.030504] BTRFS: error (device sdf: state A) in btrfs_init_new_device:2778: errno=-28 No space left
[ 1393.030548] BTRFS info (device sdf: state EA): forced readonly
```

interestingly it did not say that METADATA was full in the debug output this time.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

The "another balance is paused" should have been a big hint.  I ran:

```
mount -o rw,skip_balance /mnt && btrfs balance cancel /mnt
```

To cancel the existing balance before it forced the filesystem into read-only.  Then I was able to delete large files and rebalance normally.